# django - 1. select 2. filter 3. then cut

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to do this logic:

```
1. take all objects
2. filter them: all objs which has rate value >= 4
3. then take randomly 4 out of them.
```

how can i take randomly 4 out of them? not just cutting from end

this is my code:
 `MyObj.objects.filter(objects__rate__gte=4).distinct('id').order_by('-id')[:4]`

Comment: i think, i can do ``order_by('?')``, right?

Comment: Note: order_by('?') queries may be expensive and slow, depending on the database backend you’re using

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can use :

```
random.sample(population, k)
```

Return a `k` length list of unique elements chosen from the `population` sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement

http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample

Answer (score 1):

Django has the option to order randomly. This is done by using `.order_by('?')`.

So your code will be:

```
MyObj.objects.filter(rate__gte=4).distinct('id').order_by('?')[:4]
```

It is actually stated in the django documentation which can be views here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Comment: DatabaseError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("home_location"."id") "home_location"."i...

Comment: the problem is, i am ordering randomly taking distinct ids. this is the problem. and i also slice. a bit different from this ticket, but let me try to swap those two

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: i wont work in my case, cos i am also slicing, i cannot slice before distincht

Comment: django 1.4 and python 2.6

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33533/discussion-between-mattwritescode-and-doniyor)

Comment: Are you using Postgres or another sql database http://www.ostools.net/uploads/apidocs/django1.4/ref/models/querysets.html#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct lists that defining values in distinct is only available in postgres. Is there a need for distinct(id)?

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = MyObj.objects.filter(objects__rate__gte=4) # step 1 & 2
random.sample(list(foo), 4) # step 3 (will contain duplicates)
random.sample(set(foo), 4) # step 3, only uniques
```